# ios remove tabbar on button touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've a tab bar based project created and added a login view prior to tab view like this.

**AppDelgate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    loginView.delegate = self;

    [window addSubview:loginView.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void) loginViewControllerDidFinish:(LoginViewController *) loginViewController{
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

I'm calling loginViewControllerDidFinish: after authentication in LoginViewController as

```
[self.delegate loginViewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

Now in one of the tabs i've added logout button and want to come back to loginView on touch.

```
-(IBAction) logout:(id)sender{
    NMSAppDelegate *appDelegate = (NMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //[appDelegate.tabBarController release];
    [appDelegate.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

it shows the loginView after calling the above method but after re-login it shows all the previous data and previously selected tab but i want it to be afresh from the first tab.Is there anyway to completely delete the tabbar on logout.so that i'm starting the new session.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you create another instance of appDelegate.tabBarController ?

Something like this:

```
appDelegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:VIEW_CONTROLLER1, VIEW_CONTROLLER2,nil];

appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Do you want me to add this in loginViewControllerDidFinish: method or where? Also which view controllers are  added to the NSArray ??

Comment: You can add in loginViewController if you dont remove the same tabbar later with removeFromSuperview. You have to alloc/init every controller that will show as tab, and add then to the array.

Comment: o.k. In that case should i have to remove loginViewControllerDidFinish: delegate method as well and add the above code on successful authentication of user in LoginViewController?

Comment: you can remove the delegate method if you dont need. And yes, call it on a successful authentication.

Comment: seems that will do but i have to edit lots of things to make my app up and running in this manner. Anyways is there any way to relaunch the app or clear everything and restart from the beginning? That way all the existing objects are deleted and the app presents the login view afresh.